# GluonHq plugin can not debug

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile, gluon-desktop

I tried gluonmobile 4.1.0 and 4.2.0, when I run the "debug" task(Tasks/application/debug), it just blocks:

Executing external task 'debug'...

:compileJava UP-TO-DATE

:processResources UP-TO-DATE

:classes UP-TO-DATE

:compileDesktopJava UP-TO-DATE

:processDesktopResources UP-TO-DATE

:desktopClasses UP-TO-DATE

:debug

Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005

(Blocking forever....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Eclipse e.g. you can create a `Debug Configuration` of type `Remote Java Application` which will be attached to the corresponding socket:

[image]

After you have started the gradle `task debug` you then have to start the `Debug Configuration`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I'm using Intellj IDEA, should I do the "Debug Configuration" too?